# Using a Node ENV Variable as a default method parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, environment-variables

Long story short;
Why does this work;

```js
function func() {
  console.log(process.env.myVar)
}
```

But this does not;

```js
function func(myVar = process.env.myVar) {
  console.log(myVar)
}
```

**Context:**
I would expect function n.2 would output the value of `process.env.myVar` as well. But `myVar` appears to be `undefined`.

The function is called in a HTML  after Vue.js code evaluation.

Comment: To know why this "doesn't work" we have to know what you expect to happen. It would also be good to know how this code is evaluated.

Comment: The browser does not have environment variables

Comment: Yes, but Node hast them before the code is compiled. Question is why is Node not inserting the variable as a default?

Comment: *"Yes, but Node hast them before the code is compiled. Question is why is Node not inserting the variable as a default?"* Replacing `process.env` is a compile time step. If you use Vite then you could possible use https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-inspect to see at which step it gets replaced and dig more into that. While I find it unlikely, maybe it's a bug that default arguments are ignored one way or the other.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. I'll close this as the question is kind of off-topic